# Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given HELPPP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysql-error-1064

This is the code:

```
<?php 
require_once('config.php'); 
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Elenco Frattali</title>
</head>

<body>


<h1> Inizio pagina </h1>
<?php
$sel = "SELECT immagini.id AS id, immagini.name AS nome
        FROM immagini"  ;


$ris = mysqli_query($con,$sel);  
$count = mysqli_num_rows($ris); 


if($count >= 1)  
    echo "<h1>Elenco Studenti: </h1>";

while ( $riga=mysql_fetch_array($sel)) {   
    echo "<h3>".$riga['id']."</h3>";
       }

?>


<br>

<?php                       //chiudo while  
mysqli_close($con); //chiudo connessione
?>  
</body>
</html>
```

The error is on this line `while ( $riga=mysql_fetch_array($sel)) {`.

The error says this:

> mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given.

On this database I'm using a table with an BLOB (for storing images) ,if you need to know this. HELPPPP

Comment: Gin and tonic mix well together, but not `mysql_` and `mysqli_` functions.

Answer (score 2):

You have two errors in the same line of code:

1) You are mixing mysql and mysqli API which you cannot do

2) You are passing the query to your function instead of the result resource:

```
while($riga = mysql_fetch_array($sel)) {
```

should be:

```
while($riga = mysqli_fetch_array($ris)) {   
                 //^             ^^^^
```